# Generate an incrementally increasing sequence like 112123123412345

Tags: r, sequence, seq

Basically I want to generate a sequence, say:

n is 2, the sequence will be 112
n is 3, sequence is 112123
n is 5, sequence is 112123123412345

I did come up with a solution

```
n=5
seq=1
for (i in 2:n){
  seq=c(seq,rep(1:n,len=i))
}
```

I am wondering if there is a way can do it without for loop?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use `sequence`:

```
> sequence(1:5)
 [1] 1 1 2 1 2 3 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 5
```

Comment: There is also something somewhat satisfying in doing `sequence(sequence(5))` :-)

Comment: @Chris: make sure to read the "See Also" sections of the help files. `?seq` mentions `sequence` there.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich Thanks man, I guess I really need to build the habit of reading help page properly, I did go there but ignored everything except arguments and examples.

Answer (score 7):

Here is one possibility:

```
n<-5
unlist(lapply(1:n,function(x) 1:x))
## [1] 1 1 2 1 2 3 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 5
```

Comment: more functional, would be `unlist(lapply(seq(n),seq))`

Comment: +1, since `sequence` is defined as `function (nvec) unlist(lapply(nvec, seq_len))`.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys! Though this question can be solved by sequence(), it is actually a question from my tutorial practice, asking how to do something using lapply() instead of loop, I think this is what the tutorial question is looking for.

Comment: if you look at the sequence code you will see how similar are the responses.

Answer (score 5):

It'd do something like:

```
do.call('c', sapply(1:5, seq, from = 1))
# [1] 1 1 2 1 2 3 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 5
```

Answer (score 1):

I misread the question as "how to generate that annoying puzzler sequence,"  which goes
1,11,21,1112,3112,... :-).  So I figured I might as well write a solution to that.

```
puzseq<-function(seqlen) {
theseq<- list(1)
for( j in 2:seqlen) {

thetab<-table(theseq[[j-1]])
theseq[[j]]<-unlist( sapply( 1:length(thetab), function(k) c(thetab[k], as.numeric(names(thetab)[k])) ))
}
return(theseq)
}
```

Comment: This is difficult to read; code formatting is not standard and not consistent.

Comment: @ClaytonStanley could you clarify what you find unclear? It better be more than lack of indents for loop contents!