# Fastest way to make expanding sequence

Tags: r

Lets say we have a vector `1:5`.  How can I iterate through and each time take 1:i of the vector, creating a new vector?

Here's a slower approach.  I'm hoping for faster with `rep` or something I'm not thinking of:

```
n <- 5
nrows <- 1:n
unlist(lapply(nrows, function(i) nrows[1:i]))

[1] 1 1 2 1 2 3 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 5
```

To scale up make `n` bigger.

Comment: Fun fact: the fastest solution of those posted so far, the built-in `sequence` function, has source code that is almost identical to yours. The only difference is that it uses `seq_len`, instead of `function(i) nrows[1:i]`. This gives it an added level of vectorization. In addition, `seq_len` is a primitive written in optimized C, and the whole `sequence` function is byte-compiled (but you can byte-compile your own functions with the `compiler` package that now comes with R).

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/19317140/271616

Comment: Interestingly (or not), this is a multi-dupe question but IIRC suggesting `sequence` hasn't come up as an answer before. Maybe SO needs a "better answer" closing option (as opposed to "duplicate")

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do

```
sequence(1:n)
```

It is short and beats everything else... (so far). I also find

```
sequence(sequence(n))
```

somewhat satisfying. It is the same speedwise.

Comment: I had no idea this function existed, and it is in fact faster than any of the solutions in the other answer. Funnily enough, the source code for `sequence` is almost identical to the OP's original solution.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setkey(as.data.table(seq(n)), V1)[,list(V2=seq(V1)), by=V1]$V2
```

Or

```
 n1 <- 1:n
 seq_len(sum(n1))-rep(cumsum(c(0L, n1[-length(n1)])), n1)
```

#### Benchmarks

```
 f1 <- function() {nrows <- 1:n
                unlist(lapply(nrows, function(i) nrows[1:i]))}

 f2 <- function() {setkey(as.data.table(1:n), V1)[, list(V2=1:V1), by=V1]$V2}

 f3 <- function() {n1 <- 1:n
                seq_len(sum(n1)) - rep(cumsum(c(0L, n1[-length(n1)])), n1)}

 library(microbenchmark)
 n <- 20000
 microbenchmark(f1(), f2(), f3(), unit='relative', times=10L)
 #Unit: relative
 #expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
 #f1() 2.164453 2.329069 2.294095 2.376760 2.331996 2.159276    10   c
 #f2() 1.845572 1.885210 1.997209 2.030375 2.094401 2.147525    10  b 
 #f3() 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000    10 a
```