# How can I remove one number each time while replicating a number of sequence in r?

Tags: r

I have a sequence of numbers like this:

```
> seq(2,6,1)
[1] 2 3 4 5 6
```

I would like to replicate this sequence and remove one number from the end of the sequence while doing replication. This is what I want to have:

```
[1] 2 3 4 5 6 2 3 4 5 2 3 4 2 3 2
```

Is there any functions in R can help me get this sequence?

Thank you very much.

Comment: `sequence(5:1) + 1`: Related post [Generate an incrementally increasing sequence like 112123123412345](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19317140/generate-an-incrementally-increasing-sequence-like-112123123412345)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sure there is a fancier way, but the following code achieves the goal in base R.

```r
out = integer()
a = 2:6
while( length(a) > 1 ) {
  a = a[-length(a)]
  out = c(out, a)
}
out
#>  [1] 2 3 4 5 2 3 4 2 3 2
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

That should be it:

```
sequence(5:1, from = 2)
 [1] 2 3 4 5 6 2 3 4 5 2 3 4 2 3 2
```